# How to deploy react native application to iOS device without connecting the device to the Mac?

Tags: ios, react-native

I recently successfully completed my react native application for iOS. Now that I want to test it on a real device I am not sure how to do it without connecting the device manually. When I connect the device to the Mac, it is prompting me to update my macOS which I currently cannot do because of storage reasons. Is there any way to deploy the react native application to iOS device without connecting my iPhone to the Mac? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to push the App to the `TestFlight`.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need an apple developers account and configure an app with all the certificates and mobile provisions configuration. And then you have two options:
1 - create and Ad Hoc mobile provision so you can generate an .ipa file that can be launched on your device (you need your device's UDID for this).
2 - create an app on the app store and upload your build to test flight. Then you invite your self to the app on test flight and download the test flight app on your device